# How do you change TextField value fontSize?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the font size of my textfield which is usually done with fontSize attribute in a text composable, however textfield composable does not come with that attribute, how do I change the font size then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextField(
  textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 45.sp)
)
```

Comment: How to use font size libraries?

Comment: I don't get it. what do you mean 'font size libraries'?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)

Comment: Are you not able to use that as such?

Comment: I mean just replacing it with ssp

Comment: Long as it is an extension of `TextUnit`, it should work nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks
 Can the same method be used for dimens?

Comment: like the xml? You want to use the library in the xml?

Comment: Exactly like xml

Comment: No, I don't think so. The dp and others that you can use in the xml are pre-configured, i.e., they are built into the xml framework. If you want to use a custom size unit in xml, then it must be created specifically by the developer for working with xml, which I think is not a easy task. This is per my knowledge, you can research more if you wish to, anyway.

Comment: If you are using JC, why do you even want to use xml? Just define a dimens.kt and cram all the dimensions there. You can use any units over there. Just try to ditch xml, that is the whole point of declarative programming, which is why we shifted to Compose. XML is static, it is better to use dynamic components since they offer more flexibility.